# Two Equilateral Triangles and the Golden Ratio: Simple Geomtric Proof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

Two equilateral triangles rest upon the same horizontal line, as shown in the linked figure below.

The red triangle is tilted so that one corner touches a side of the black triangle at the midpoint of the side.  A perpendicular line is drawn from the midpoint of the right side of the red triangle through the point where the red triangle touches the black triangle, until it reaches the left side of the black triangle.  The line is divided into a yellow segment and a blue segment at the point where the two triangles touch.  What is the ratio between the yellow and blue lines?  (Hint: It should be the golden ratio ~1.681....)

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the ratio is golden? (A similar prediction in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1759803/409) was incorrect.) If the triangles are congruent, I have a GeoGebra sketch and some coordinate bashing in Mathematica that calculate the yellow-to-blue ratio as $$\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{4}\;=\;1.65138\dots$$

Comment: @Blue, that's half the [bronze ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean)...

Comment: The OP should say whether the triangles are congruent.

Comment: @lhf: Nice catch! :) I haven't run across the other metallic means often enough to recognize them on sight.

Comment: When I woke up this morning the golden ratio was 1.618... . What changed? Typo maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since there's a trigonometry tag, here's such an approach, which yields Blue's answer:

From the OP's picture, I assume that the two triangles are congruent. Then, the sine law implies that in $\triangle BED$:
$$\sin \frac{2\pi}{3}:\sin \beta = DE:DB = 2.$$
Thus $$\sin \beta=\frac{\sqrt3}{4},\cos \beta=\frac{\sqrt{13}}4.\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, 
$$\begin{aligned}\gamma &= \pi - (\angle ADB +\alpha +\angle DEG) \\
&=\pi -\left(\frac\pi2+\alpha+\frac\pi6\right)\\
&= \frac\pi3-\alpha\\
&=\beta.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, $\triangle ADH$ and $\triangle AED$ are similar, and we get
$$AD:HD = AE:DE$$
Since $AD=DG$ and $AB=DE$, the ratio we are looking for is
$$\frac{AE}{DE} = 1+ \frac{BE}{DE}=1+\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin 2\pi/3}.$$
The answer follows from (1) and the fact that
$$\sin \alpha = \sin \left(\frac\pi3-\beta\right)=\sin \frac\pi3\cos\beta-\cos\frac\pi3\sin\beta.$$

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't $\beta $ be any value?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN because of the constrain that $DE=2DB$.

Comment: How did you get $ DE=2DB $

Comment: @N.S.JOHN $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and the *assumption* that the two equilateral triangles are congruent.

Comment: That is not given in the question. The question only says that $DC$is the perpendicular bisector of $FE $

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I mentioned the assumption from the beginning of the proof. The question doesn't say anything about the relation of the two triangles. Apparently the said ratio cannot be a constant without the said relation.

Comment: I do not see that assumption.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Working-through the problem with arbitrary side lengths, say $|\overline{AB}| = p$ and $|\overline{DE}| = q$, the desired ratio is $$\frac{3p+\sqrt{16q^2-3p^2}}{4p}$$  One can determine that, in order to achieve OP's proposed outcome (the golden ratio between the specified lengths), we must have $$\frac{q}{p}\;=\;\frac{1}{2}\;\sqrt{6-\sqrt{5}} \;\approx\; 0.97$$ It seems likely that experimentation with congruent triangles led OP to conjecture the involvement of the golden ratio.